# VirtualStringTree: Fix node hitbox after OnBeforeCellPaint

Tags: delphi, virtualtreeview, tvirtualstringtree

I've for a virtualstringtree control on my form which has to display icons from an imagelist for certain nodes. This works fine, however, it also has to display custom drawn icons that are as tall as the node and square, for certain nodes.

I'm using the OnBeforeCellPaint event to draw these images and change the ContentRect to accommodate for the extra space it requires in the item.

```
ContentRect.Offset(ContentRect.Height + 4, 0);
```

(The +4 is there to have the same spacing from the "icon" for the text as with the ones loaded from the imagelist)

This method seems to work fine, the nodes are drawn correctly and the selection rectangles are as well. However, the hitboxes for clicking the nodes don't seem to get updated. I have to click the original ContentRect to select the node.

How do I update the hitbox?

Comment: You should use the OnMeasureItem event to set the node height.

Comment: The height isn't the issue, the width is, or is it a standard requirement?

Comment: Maybe you might consider to rephrase the question (or at least the title) to something about changing node size. What you've been trying is a wrong way (drawing out of node's *physical* position), but it's an interesting topic which might be useful to someone else in a future. With the current title and content it's hard to understand, that you've been trying to change the node extent. Pity I've been away when you've asked this question and that I didn't noticed it later on. You might get the answer in few hours instead of almost month and half :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

***What to avoid ?***

Don't modify the `ContentRect` in the `OnBeforeCellPaint` if you want to change the size of a node. The `ContentRect` rectangle in the `OnBeforeCellPaint` event is for modifying the place, where the cell will be rendered. It doesn't actually modify the size of a node. By that `ContentRect` offset you just moved painting out of the node's *physical* position, out from the position where the node can be clicked.

***How to adjust node height ?***

The default, fixed node height is defined by the `DefaultNodeHeight` property. When you don't know the node height you need in advance, you can write the handler for the `OnMeasureItem` event. There you can modify the `NodeHeight` parameter value to adjust the height of a node.

When you'll be handling the `OnMeasureItem` event, be sure to include the `toVariableNodeHeight` option to the `TreeOptions.MiscOptions` option set.

***How to adjust node width ?***

For `TVirtualStringTree` control specifically, the node width is calculated by the measured node text width increased by 2 * text margin (adjustable by the `TextMargin` property). During the node text width measurement the `OnMeasureTextWidth` event is fired having the declared `Extent` parameter, which contains the measured text width. By modifying this `Extent` parameter, you'll affect the overall width of a node since this event is internally used just for this purpose.

So, to increase each node width e.g. by 20 pixels, you can write the following:

```
procedure TForm1.VirtualStringTree1MeasureTextWidth(Sender: TBaseVirtualTree;
  TargetCanvas: TCanvas; Node: PVirtualNode; Column: TColumnIndex;
  const Text: string; var Extent: Integer);
begin
  Extent := Extent + 20;
end;
```

Here is the result without and with the text extent modified:

[image]

For `TVirtualDrawTree` control is the situation much easier. It has the `OnGetNodeWidth` event, that is used to specify a node width through its `NodeWidth` declared parameter.